# How secure is a partial 64bit hash of a SHA1 160bit hash?

Tags: encryption, sha

So http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

> SHA-1 produces a 160-bit (20-byte) hash value

and

> As of 2012, the most efficient attack against SHA-1 is considered to be the one by Marc Stevens with an estimated cost of $2.77M to break a single hash value by renting CPU power from cloud servers

With a theoretical attack taking 2^60 operations

So if a custom verification algorithm only the first 64bits of the full hash how secure is that?

How many operations would it require?

Answer (score 3):

The attack described by Marc Stevens, and all other known attacks on SHA-1 as well, are about **collisions**. Finding a collision is about finding two distinct sequences of bits *m* and *m'* such that both hash to the same value.

Collisions are **irrelevant** to the use of SHA-1 for *verification*. When using SHA-1 for verifying some data, there is a hash value *v*, and the attacker's goal is to find a bit sequence *m* (e.g., a password, if we are talking about verifying passwords) such that *m* hashes to *v*. This is called a **preimage** and it is not the same animal at all as collisions. For all we know, SHA-1's resistance to preimages is as good as new.

Let's put some numbers on it. For a hash function with *n* bits of output, a collision can be found with average cost *2<sup>n/2</sup>* evaluations of the hash function (this is related to the so-called [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)) so this would amount to about *2<sup>80</sup>* calls to SHA-1 for the full function. This kind of attack is completely generic, it works with all hash functions; Stevens' attack is considered a break because it does better, down to an estimated cost of *2<sup>61</sup>* evaluations of the function: half a million times faster than the generic attack, but still quite expensive (*2<sup>61</sup>* is about 2 billions of billions). If you truncate the output to 64 bits then the generic attack cost is down to *2<sup>32</sup>* and a PC will be able to find a collision in a few minutes. Fortunately, as I said above, collisions don't impact the use of the hash function for verification, since that use relies on resistance to preimages.

For preimages, a generic attack on hash function is called "get lucky": try random input sequences *m* until one is found that matches the target output. For a hash function with an output of *n* bits, this has average cost *2<sup>n</sup>*. For the full SHA-1, this leads to *2<sup>160</sup>* which is very far in the unfeasible realm (quite beyond the "sci-fi feasible", even). If you truncate the SHA-1 output to 64 bits, then that cost goes down to *2<sup>64</sup>*, which is technologically feasible, but will be expensive. Let's estimate the cost: a good GPU costing a few hundreds of dollars will go through about 2 billions of SHA-1 computations per second, let's say *2<sup>31</sup>* to make computations easy; so that GPU will need about *2<sup>33</sup>* seconds to run the preimage attack (because *2<sup>64</sup> = 2<sup>33</sup>*2<sup>31</sup>*). *2<sup>33</sup>* seconds, that's 272 years... If you put 3000 such GPU to the task (so that's a million dollar cost for the hardware alone), it will take about one month to find a 64-bit preimage.

[FPGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) might lower the hardware cost, but will increase development costs a lot, because that's no longer a matter of putting together some off-the-shelf PC. A *practical* attacker will rent GPU time from big cloud provider such as [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) (their "CG1 instances" are what the attacker would use in this case).

Therefore, for many purposes where what the hash/verification system protects in not too expensive in itself, truncating the SHA-1 output to 64 bits will not imply an actual security vulnerability.

Now the **important notes**:

- All of the above assumes that SHA-1 truncated to 64 bits (let's call it SHA-1/64) is as good against preimages as can be expected from a "perfect" hash function, and as SHA-1 itself seems to be with its full 160 bits. It can be shown that SHA-1/64 cannot be too weak against preimages, because a very fast attack against SHA-1/64 could be turned into an attack against the full SHA-1 which would be faster than *2<sup>160</sup>* (not *fast*, but *faster*, which would be enough for an academic paper). No such attack is known, so it can be assumed that SHA-1/64 is *probably* resistant to preimage up to cost *2<sup>64</sup>*.
- If you are hashing *passwords* then **you are doing it wrong**. Password hashing has some special needs, because passwords are inherently weak (humans accept to remember them and to type them, so they cannot be strong). When dealing with passwords, the biggest vulnerability is the password itself, not the hashing function. SHA-1/64, or SHA-1, are by themselves very poor, because they are very fast, and unsalted (which allows for precomputations and parallel attacks). Please read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/655) which will tell you how password hashing should be done.

  (If you are hashing passwords then the answer to your question "how many operations would it require ?" will be the same for SHA-1/64 and for the full SHA-1, i.e.: about one billion. Because user-chosen passwords rarely exceed 30 bits of entropy. A good GPU will need less than a second to do that...)